# Edit Bootstrap Modal Popup not Loading Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a details view of a Model `TModel` that displays the details of a record as Read only and has a button that should load the edit view (modal). So I have the modal container in `_layout.cshtml` and my partial view created in the shared folder but when the button from the details view is clicked it only shows the modal without the form from the partialview.

**Modal in Layout**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditCompanyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body p-0">
                <div class="p-5 BigShadow">
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold">
                        Edit Company Account
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o text-tomato"></i></span>
                    </h5>
                    <span class="small">Please ensure that information provided is valid</span>
                    <hr style="border-top: 1px dashed #EEE" />

                    @*@await Html.PartialAsync("CompanyModalPartial")*@
                    <div class="modal-content">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript in Layout**

```
$('#EditCompanyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#EditCompanyModal modal-content').load('@Url.Action("ModalDetails", "Company")')
});
```

**Action in Company Controller**

```
public IActionResult ModalDetails()
{
    return PartialView("CompanyModalPartial");
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model TModel
<form asp-action="Save">
    //form
</form>
```

Note that the partial view has the same model as the Details View.
So with the above appraoch, when I click the edit button, the modal displays but there's no form. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there're two bugs in your jQuery codes :

```
$('#EditCompanyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#EditCompanyModal modal-content').load('@Url.Action("ModalDetails", "Company")')
});
```

1. the  **`$('#EditCompanyModal modal-content')`** is not a valid selector , there's no `<modal-content>` html tag at all.
2. the **`'hidden.bs.modal'`** event will not be fired before show .

to show the modal with the partial view , change your code as below :

```js
$('#EditCompanyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#EditCompanyModal .modal-content').load('@Url.Action("ModalDetails", "Company")')
});
$('#EditCompanyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#EditCompanyModal .modal-content').html("");
});
```

It will works as expected .